# Update Main Menu DataGridView when I update database from another form

Tags: c#

I have 3 Forms: `frmMain_Menu`, `frmEmployee` (which has the datagridview) and `frmAdd_Employee`.

`frmMain_Menu` has a button named `btnEmployee` and a panel `SamplePanel`.

`frmEmployee` has a button named `btnAddEmployee` and a datagridview `dgvEmployee`.

`frmAdd_Employee` has a button named `btnSave`.

When I click `btnEmployee`, it will show `frmEmployee` inside `SamplePanel`.
When I click `btnAddEmployee` it will show `frmAdd_Employee`.

After input of data and clicking `btnSave` I want to update and display the newly saved data which was inserted and saved from `frmAdd_Employee` inside `dgvEmployee`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi PotatoLord welcome to Stackoverflow :D

You can call frmAdd_Employee using showDialog and after the save you set de dialog result to ok.

Something like that

```
var formAdd = new frmAdd_Employee();
if(formAdd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
 //reload your grid
}
```

And there in your frmAdd after the save you can call

```
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
```

That way your add form will open as a dialog and the frmEmployee will wait til a dialog result, and if the result is OK you do the grid reload

Comment: thanks for the code, I have tried it. It worked perfectly!